# Datagridview vertical alignment in datetime input column

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have an application for windows made in visual basic. In a Windows Form there is a Datagridview with several columns. In all of them the vertical alignment is Middlecenter. The data is displayed correctly in the Text type columns, but in a column that is of the Datetime type the data is displayed in the lower part of the cells. Is it possible to see this data in the middle part of the cells?

Comment: That sounds like WPF..... which has nothing whatsoever to do with VBA. Would be helpful to see the actual XAML markup (assuming WPF... or is it WinForms... too many tags and information are missing for this question to be answerable in any way) you're using for the columns.... please [edit] your post after reading [mcve].

Comment: We're going to need to see the column properties or code or something.

Answer (score 0):

In your form_load try:

```
  DGV1.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment.MiddleCenter
```

Assuming your datagridview is called DGV1 and the column with your Date-Time is column 3.

BR
Fnk

Comment: That's what I have done, but instead of doing it with code, I do it in the DataGrid properties for each of the columns. That is why I have verified that it works correctly in all columns except the DateTime type. I do not know if another property has to be modified so that the presentation is correct or it is a failure of the DataGrid and it is not possible to get this presentation. Thank you for your answers. Greetings.